# Which language should choose when publishing an app in Google play?

Tags: google-play, blogger

I have a doubt regarding publishing blog app to the **Google Play**, My app is almost in English language but app content is different which is in another language. So, which language I should select when publishing it to the Google Play?

Comment: As you wish ...

Comment: Are you targeting it for English speaking users? Then English. There's no rue against that. A Gernan-English dictionary, for example, would have a lot of content in German, but it's intended audience is still Anglophone.